# how to modify pocketsphinx continuous.c

Tags: raspberry-pi2, pocketsphinx

i was trying to make word that was detected to execute file.py.
here the source code that i try to modify at continuous.c

```
if (!in_speech && utt_started) {
        /* speech -> silence transition, time to start new utterance  */
        ps_end_utt(ps);
        hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL );
    if (hyp = "OPEN"){
        fopen("/home/pi/project/open.py", "r");
    }
        if (hyp != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", hyp);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
```

the program still detect the word but it still not execute the program that i want.
and here is the command that i was using

```
 pocketsphinx_continuous -lm /home/pi/project/3379.lm -dict /home/pi/project/3379.dic -samprate 16000/8000/48000 -inmic yes -adcdev plughw:1,0
```

really need help here. thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C strings are compared with `strcmp`, not with `=`, with `=` you just assign pointers, not even compare them.

It should be

```
if (strcmp(hyp, "OPEN") == 0) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help @Nikolay . i was noticed that too. but the most important, i dont know they must be compiled on terminal using "gcc .....". i just compile them in app and of course it will not compiled well. and the conclusion i just miss that point. many thanks to you nikolay, i really appreciate your answer ^^